# How do you scrape from a website which requires credentials (SSL)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.  I want to scrape html/text contents from an SSL enabled website (https in the URL).  There will be multiple branches in the filesystem of said site.

My questions is:

How do I go about providing credentials for the external website from within my Rails application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'httpclient'
require 'nokogiri'

client = HTTPClient.new

client.set_auth("http://domain.com", "username", "password")

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(c.get_content("http://example.com"))
```

Hey guys, sorry about the late response, I've been swamped with a few things.  The code above worked for me. (after many tangos with mechanize and some of the other nokogiri-based gems).  The some of the other gems such as openuri, mechanize, etc were resulting in errors such as MD5 Unknown hashing algorithm.  Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Typhoeus gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/typhoeus).

I struggled with this problem before as well.

*ANSWER*

However, if you use Typhoeus,

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Typhoeus # Checking that Typhoeus gem is being used.
 => Typhoeus 
1.9.3p194 :002 > url = "https://twitter.com/"
 => "https://twitter.com/" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > response = Typhoeus::Request.get(url, :timeout => 5000)

 => #<Typhoeus::Response:0x007fdd8cc00488 @code=200, @curl_return_code=0, @curl_error_message="No error", @status_message=nil, @http_version=nil, @headers="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 23:56:32 GMT\r\nStatus: 200 OK\r\nX-Runtime: 0.08814\r\nX-MID: 0cfcab7a410834bf31115f9a5cd7fb62651aa568\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138519\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 23:56:32 GMT\r\nETag: \"95db45f50f8dc1a45be3895e03a23d53\"\r\nExpires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT\r\nX-Transaction: 72253ef75f0755e1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nSet-Cookie: k=10.35.35.113.1348617392068257; path=/; expires=Tue, 02-Oct-12 23:56:32 GMT; domain=.twitter.com\r\nSet-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A134861739271966362; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 26-Sep-2014 11:56:32 GMT\r\nSet-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CToPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCFBS3P85AToMY3NyZl9pZCIlNTY2MzNjOTM0%250AOTIyMDE4ZmNkY2E4NjViZmE3ZTBkMDAiCmZsYXNoSUM6J0FjdGlvbkNvbnRy%250Ab2xsZXI6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7AAY6CkB1c2VkewA6B2lkIiViYjAw%250AY2Q1YWZkMDAwNmExNWJhNjAyYmNiNzBhOTA0Yg%253D%253D--5ffbea931432fe65a2128be90048e3bb6fc9dbca; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nContent-Length: 13733\r\nServer: tfe\r\n\r\n", @body="<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    \n    <script>document.domain='twitter.com'</script>\n\n      <title>Twitter</title>\n\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">\n    \n      <meta name=\"description\" content=\"Instantly connect to what&#39;s most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news.\">\n    \n    \n      <link href=\"/favicons/favicon.ico\" rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n    \n    \n          <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1348559220/t1/css/t1_core_logged_out.bundle.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">\n    \n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/13485592

1.9.3p194 :005 >    response.body # returns html document
 => "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    \n    <script>document.domain='twitter.com'</script>\n\n      <title>Twitter</title>\n\n    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">\n    \n      <meta name=\"description\" content=\"Instantly connect to what&#39;s most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news.\">\n    \n    \n      <link href=\"/favicons/favicon.ico\" rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n    \n    \n          <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1348559220/t1/css/t1_core_logged_out.bundle.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">\n    \n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1348559220/t1/css/t1_more.bundle.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">\n    \n          <script>\n      (function() {\n        function getPhxPath(){var a=l.href.match(/#(.)(.*)$/);return a&&a[1]==\"!\"&&a[2]}function getEvent(a){return a?(a=a.replace(/^#|\\/$/,\"\").toLowerCase(),a.match(/^[a-z0-9_]+$/)?a:!1):!1}function redirectEventPath(a){var a=getEvent(a);if(a){var b=document.referrer||\"none\",c=\"ev_redir_\"+a+\"=\"+b+\"; path=/\";document.cookie=c,l.replace(\"/hashtag/\"+a)}}function resolveInlineRedirects(){var a=getPhxPath();a&&l.replace(a),l.hash!=\"\"&&redirectEventPath(l.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase())}var l=window.location;resolveInlineRedirects(),window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener(\"hashchange\",resolveInlineRedirects,!1):window.attachEvent&&window.attachEvent(\"onhashchange\",resolveInlineRedirects);\n      }());\n      </script>\n    \n    <script>\n      \n      \n      (func
```

Good luck!

Comment: Net/http supports https, but you need to set the use_ssl flag on the request

Comment: Thanks Frederick. Removed that bit now.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with this. It's not that hard actually.

```
open("http://...", :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password])
```

And if you want to parse you can even adapt my crawler.
Here is the main method in it.

```
require "open-uri"
require "zlib"

SHINSO_HEADERS = {
  'Accept'          => '*/*',
  'Accept-Charset'  => 'utf-8, windows-1251;q=0.7, *;q=0.6',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate',
  'Accept-Language' => 'bg-BG, bg;q=0.8, en;q=0.7, *;q=0.6',
  'Connection'      => 'keep-alive',
  'Cookie'          => '',
  'From'            => 'email@example.com',
  'Referer'         => 'http://svejo.net/',
  'User-Agent'      => 'Your user agent'
}

def crawl(url_address)
  self.errors = Array.new
  begin
    begin
      url_address = URI.parse(url_address)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      url_address = URI.decode(url_address)
      url_address = URI.encode(url_address)
      url_address = URI.parse(url_address)
    end
    url_address.normalize!
    stream = ""
    timeout(8) { stream = url_address.open(SHINSO_HEADERS) }
    if stream.size > 0
      url_crawled = URI.parse(stream.base_uri.to_s)
    else
      self.errors << "Server said status 200 OK but document file is zero bytes."
      return
    end
  rescue Exception => exception
    self.errors << exception
    return
  end
end
```

**url_crawled** is what you need in the end.

Try using this address for the test.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

If your still experience an error your server might not be configured right, certificate wise and you should check that out.

And on a related note if you are serious about parsing you might also consider using CharGuess gem and Zlib for reading the content right and then converting the problematic ones with Iconv. Here is an example.

```
if    stream.content_encoding.include?('gzip')
  document = Zlib::GzipReader.new(stream).read
elsif stream.content_encoding.include?('deflate')
  document = Zlib::Deflate.new().deflate(stream).read
#elsif stream.content_encoding.include?('x-gzip') or
#elsif stream.content_encoding.include?('compress')
else
  document = stream.read
end
self.charset_guess = CharGuess.guess(document)
```

Then just use Iconv on the content.

Hope this helps you.

Regards,
Yavor